# 'pip3' not found when installing pip3 on suse15 linux failed

Tags: python, linux, pip, suse, zypper

Hit the following issue when installing pip3 on suse15 linux. How to fix this issue?

```
*> sudo zypper install pip3
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
**'pip3' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'pip3' found.**
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Suse, but I think the name of the package is [`python3-pip`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/python3-pip).